# How to Send Post request in java with javax.portlet.ActionResponse.sendRedirect method?

Tags: servlets, portlet

I want to POST to URL but following making it as GET , so How can I POST the

```
    Object portletResponse = webAppAccess.getHttpServletRequest()
            .getAttribute(Constants.PORTLET_RESPONSE);

   if (portletResponse instanceof javax.portlet.ActionResponse) {
            javax.portlet.ActionResponse actionResponse = (javax.portlet.ActionResponse) portletResponse;

            actionResponse.sendRedirect(URL);
        }
```

Comment: Redirect is always GET, by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this by using FORM POST method as follows.

```
 webAppAccess.processPage("importedPage");
```

Added this imported Page in model  :

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<title>New Page</title>
</HEAD>
<Body onload="">
<form id="FormID" method="POST" action="actionURL">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="ID" value="<%=webAppAccess.getVariables().getString("ID")%>"/>
    <noscript>
        <p>Your browser does not support JavaScript or it is disabled. 
            Please click the button below to process the request.
    </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Proceed " name ="submit"></input>
    </noscript>
    <script>
    document.getElementById('FormID').submit();
    </script>
</form>
```

and then MVC controller mapping as follows:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = {"/Details"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String mthDetails(final Model p_model, @RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) final String p_ID){ 

    //code for further logic using ID
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `RequestDispater` instead of response.sendRedirect?

It retains the original request, without changing it.

So, it will remain POST if it was POST.

Comment: and I want to send this from WAS to tomcat